# Парсинг сайта с кнопкой "загрузить еще"

Tags: python, парсер

Я пытаюсь собрать информацию с определенного веб ресурса с помощью Python и библиотек BeautifulSoup и requests. Все хорошо, если бы не одно но! Когда долистываешь страницу до конца есть кнопка "загрузить еще" и все что ниже (то, что подгружается) не парсится.

Читал документацию к либам - не помогло (возможно плохо читал).
Пробовал решить проблему с помощью автоматического клика - не помогло

Как можно было бы решить эту проблему?

Comment: посмотрите selenium

Comment: Ты в браузер то посмотри. Там js подгружает. А подгружает все тем же http запросом. Ну вот и изучи что там за запрос.

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо за ответы. Я использовал selenium и драйвер для хрома (chromedriver).
Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to driver")

driver.get('https://example.com')

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath of the li you are trying to access')
button.click()
```

я использовал поиск элемента по xPath, так как до кнопки надо было еще долистать

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите по-простому, то можно использовать selenium, а если вам не нужно открывать браузер, то отправьте точно такой же запрос, что и кнопка 'загрузить ещё'